# How to connect input from text_area_tag/email_field_tag to database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database

This is my code

from index.html.erb

```
<%= form_for index_path, :method => "POST"  do %>
  <%= label_tag :name, "Enter your full name: " %>
  <%= text_field_tag :name, @name, :placeholder => "Enter your name" %><br/>

  <%= label_tag :email, "Enter your e-mail address: " %>
  <%= email_field_tag :email, @email, :placeholder => "something@domain.com" %><br/>
  <%= label_tag :question, "Type your question: " %>
  <%= text_area_tag :question, @question, :size => "30x5", :placeholder => "Your text goes here", :maxlength => "130" %><br/>




  <%= submit_tag "Ask Question" %>
```

from Blog Controller

```
class BlogController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @name = params['name']
    @email = params['email']
    @question = params['question']
  end

  def about
  end

  def contact
  end
end
```

And from seeds.rb:

```
Invitation.create(:name => "#{@name}", :email => "#{@email}", :question => "#{@question}")
```

When I fill all fields and submit, it creates blank record in database, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: This is not directly related to your question. But... It seems very unusual that you are trying to create a record in an `index` action. Also, it looks like you're trying to create an `Invitation` in the `BlogController`, which also seems very unusual. Why not use the `create` action of an `InvitationController`?

Comment: I was just wondering how can I can create my own form and connect it with a model without using scaffolding. Made this just for testing, thanks anyway

Comment: Try and get out of the habit of doing things like `"#{x}"` where `x` is what you mean, or in rare occasions `x.to_s` to force it to a string. Also try and use the Ruby 1.9 hash declaration style, it's been around for ages: `create(name: @name, email: @email, ...)` It's far less verbose and more consistent with other languages.

Comment: Note: If you're editing a model it's expected you'll use `form_for` with the model passed in and then `form.email_field` and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are doing it wrong. You can't access the *instance variables* that are defined in the controller inside `seeds.rb`. Instead you just need to create the record inside the `index` action

```
def index
  @name = params['name']
  @email = params['email']
  @question = params['question']
  Invitation.create(:name => @name, :email => @email, :question => @question)
end
```

`seeds.rb` is used to create records with default values to seed the database. Normally these values are *hardcoded*.

Comment: Thanks! but why it makes one blank record apart from one that is filled? I deleted all from seeds.rb

Comment: @synopsa Did you run `rake db:seed` when you have that code in `seeds.rb`? If so it creates blank record as `@name`, `@email` and `@question` all are nil